# JavaScript toString() method is not working for JSON in karate v 1.1.0

Tags: karate

In karate version 0.9.6 the following code was working fine

```
* def response = { "firstName": "John", "lastName" : "doe", "age"      : 26, "address"  : { "streetAddress": "applewood", "city"         : "Nara", "postalCode"   : "630-0192" } }
* match response.toString() contains 'applewood'
```

But in karate version 1.1.0, The assertion failing with:

> match failed: CONTAINS
> $ | actual does not contain expected
> (STRING:STRING)
> '[object Object]'
> 'applewood'
>
> classpath:...some classpath

Even I printed the `response.toString()` and its printing `[object Object]`.

Is there any change in JS function support in karate feature files in v1.1.0?

Comment: yes. we spent MONTHS asking for RC feedback: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this change:

```
* match karate.toString(response) contains 'applewood'
```

A couple more points:

- I consider what you are doing as bad-practice. It is better to narrow down the match to a single field
- Also be aware of "type conversion": https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. The `response` is in Json format so no need to `toJson()`  what i identify is its `karate.toString(response)` which would work. and other could be `* string responseInStr = response
* match responseInStr contains 'applewood'`

Comment: on point 1:  The code in question is sample code. In real time we are checking whether response should contains `error` word to test some negative scenarios. The problem is its been used in 100+ places. So need to update all the occurrences if we plan to upgrade to 1.1.0 or later.

Comment: @NarendraR the problem for us is we would like early feedback when we take so much time to publish RC versions. none of the examples show the use of `response.toString()`. you have used an un-documented API so you are on your own now